# Access I2C/SPI/UART bus directly through /dev/mem in Java

Tags: java, i2c, spi, memory-mapping, iot

is it possible to control devices connected via I2C/SPI/UART bus directly through /dev/mem so that I could just map the memory into MappedByteBuffer talk to I2C/SPI/UART that way? 
Currently, we are using C library that uses kernel calls like `ioctl` through JNI. However I want to get rid of the JNI and have it all in pure Java, thus I want to avoid using JNI/JNA.